# Change of variable in an integral that contain a gradient

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, change-of-variable, singular-integrals

Let $\Omega\subset{\mathbb{R}^3}$ be a bounded lipschitz domain and $D$ be a $3\times 3$ real invertible matrix.
For a fixed $x\in\Omega$, consider the following integral, defined in the principal value sense
$$
A(x):=\int_{\Omega}\nabla_yg(x-y)\cdot u(u)\;d(y)
$$
where $\displaystyle g(x-y)=\frac{1}{|x-y|}$ and $u\in (L^2(\Omega))^3$ (the space of square integrable functions).
Then, if we do the change of variable $y=Dz$, how the last integral become?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $\nabla_y= D\nabla_z$, so (if I did the change of variables right!) your integral becomes
$$
A(x)= \int_{D^{-1}\Omega} D^{-t}\nabla_z g(x-Dz)\cdot u(Dz) |\det(D)|\, dz. 
$$

Comment: thank you. But I did not understand how to prove that $\nabla_y=D\nabla_z$. Could you please clarify it to me ?

Comment: @SAKLY: I made a mistake; it should be $\nabla_y = D^{-1}\nabla_z$ (for instance the chain rule would give $$\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial y_i} =\sum_j \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial z_j}\dfrac{\partial z_j}{\partial y_i},$$ and the partials of $z$ with respect to $y$ involve $D^{-1}$.